# Angular 2, throttleTime on observable from subject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Im trying to make throttleTime take effect, but for some reason it does not kick in. I have the following:

```
// Class Properties    
private calendarPeriodSubject: Subject<x> = new Subject<x>();
private calendarPeriodObservable$ = this.calendarPeriodSubject.asObservable();


// Throttling fails here (Inside constructor):
const calendarPeriodSubscription = this.calendarPeriodObservable$.pipe(throttleTime(750)).subscribe(async (calendar: x) => {
    // Do http stuff here
  }
});
```

The subject gets called like this:

```
this.calendarPeriodSubject.next(x);
```

I also tried with:

```
this.calendarPeriodSubject.pipe(throttleTime(1000)).subscribe({next: (x) => x});
```

I would like to process the FIRST time, and the following clicks should not have any effect before after ieg 750ms - To prevent the server from getting spammed basically.

Anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If you could recreate and isolate the problem in stack blitz I would be happy to help. Until then, here is some documentation I found from rxjs: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html

Comment: This wouldn't prevent the server from getting spammed, it will just "delay" it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using the wrong operator for your use case. The way I understand your explanation you want to send through your first call and stop any further calls to your Server for some amount of ms. But what `throttleTime(sec)` does is simply put a timer on the action and execute it `sec` ms later. So you server will still be spammed, just a few ms later.

Your case screams `debounceTime()` for me. [debounceTime docu](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html)

This disables any further data to be passed though the Observable for the specified time after a value has been emitted.

Therefore your code should be fine if you use something like:

```
const calendarPeriodSubscription = 
this.calendarPeriodObservable$.pipe(debounceTime(750)).subscribe((calendar: x) => {
    // Stuff with returned data
});
```

Comment: thanks to @c_ogoo for figuring it out before me in the comments take my +1 :)